# How to copy a image?

Tags: node.js, fs

I want to copy `image.png` form `/folder1` to `/folder2`, how to do it?

```
/folder1
  image.png
/folder2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var inStr = fs.createReadStream('/your/path/to/file');
var outStr = fs.createWriteStream('/your/path/to/destination');

inStr.pipe(outStr);
```

Code is not tested, just written down from memory.

Answer (score 12):

Or if you prefer callbacks:

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('folder1/image.png', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    fs.writeFile('folder2/image.png', data, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('It\'s saved!');
    });
});
```