# copy an image in nodeJs with fs

Tags: node.js, npm, fs

Im trying to copy an png file from a folder to another folder in my nodeJs project.i have some problem. new Image file has some problem and cant open.
i use this code

```
const  fs = require('fs');

     var inStr = fs.createReadStream(mainDir+"/"+req.body.ExRequestId+".png");

        var outStr = fs.createWriteStream(mainDir+"/"+docReq._id + ".png");

        inStr.pipe(outStr);
```

Comment: Try second method from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212293/how-to-copy-a-image). If the same problem persists, then I guess you have some problem with the original image itself.

Comment: @AjayDabas i try it but does not work. new image is empty

Comment: What version of Node are you using? Node added `copyFile` procedure from Node 8.5.0.
Try to use it instead. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293857/fastest-way-to-copy-file-in-node-js) to find out how.

Comment: @ArminTaghavizad v11.0.9
when i use copyFile , it done but its empty and does not have any data to show image

Comment: If you're using a lower version of node <= 8.5.0 you can use this package which extends the native `fs` module. https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra. This is a very common and popular package.

Answer (score 2):

When working with streams, it's good practice to wait for streams to become ready before using them and handle the errors.

The following snippet waits for the `ready` event on both streams before piping the ReadStream to the WriteStream and handles the errors.

```
// assuming you're using express and the app instance is bound to a variable named app

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');    

// ...

// helper function: returns a promise that gets resolved when the specified event is fired
const waitForEvent = (emitter, event) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => emitter.once(event, resolve));

app.post('/handle-post', async (req, res) => {
    // TODO: validate the input
    const { ExRequestId } = req.body;

    const srcFileName = `${path.join(mainDir, ExRequestId)}.png`;
    const destFileName = `${path.join(mainDir, docReq._id)}.png`;

    const srcStream = fs.createReadStream(srcFileName);    
    await waitForEvent(srcStream, "ready");
    const destStream = fs.createWriteStream(destFileName);    
    await waitForEvent(destStream, "ready");

    const handleError = err => res.status(500).json(err);
    srcStream.on("error", handleError);
    destStream.on("error", handleError);

    srcStream.pipe(destStream);
    await waitForEvent(srcStream, 'end');

    res.status(200).json({srcFileName, destFileName});
});
```

I also put together a minimal working example. It can be found [here](https://repl.it/@fardjad/so-59597439).

Answer (score 1):

try with this code:

```
fs.readFile(sourcePath , function (err, data) {
 if (err) throw err;
 fs.writeFile(destinationPath , data , 'base64' , function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
   console.log('It\'s saved!');
 });
});
```